# save application status in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, apache-tomee

I use Apache Tomcat 8 .
I deploy multiple application on this application server , and manage this apps by tomcat application manager .

my problem is :
tomcat don't save application status , so after restart by default start all applications with status by **running** .

I need solution for save status .
for example , if application is stopped , I want to tomcat don't start application after restart server .

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be:

Write an application (war file), JSP servlet based secured application. In which you can define, which application you dont want to start. 
Store this information in DB. Write a servlet which will load on startup and in init method of it write a code that will fetch all the applications that you dont want to start. Write a code in that method which will execute following commands for each application.

```
$ tomcat-manager --user=admin --password=somepwd \
> http://localhost:8080/manager/ stop /myapp
```

Make sure this application should get deployed at last.

I have not tried it, but it can be a possible solution.

Comment: That is not good idea , maybe web application has listener and executed on startup and then stop by your solution .

Comment: Yes, it will get stopped, that what  he wants, he dont want to run that application.

Comment: does not work , because ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] not started , so can not call tomcat URL deployment api .